# Java error configuring jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, java-web-start

I have a web java project that when running some pages give me the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
Error building SqlSession.
The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.datasource.DataSourceException: There was an error configuring JndiDataSourceTransactionPool. Cause: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: jdbc/DashDBtest
```

I have the credentials of the database, but I do not know how to configure it to work

Comment: Which container are you running the application in? It looks like you are missing the JNDI configuration of your Tomcat/JBoss/Jetty.

Comment: im running the application in ibm bluemix, liberty

Comment: I'm not familiar with that platform but the following link might be helpful... https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16218/bluemix-mysql-service-jndi-binding-on-liberty-profile-not-working.html?childToView=16222#comment-16222

Answer (score 0):

This error may related to DataSource configuration. if you use Apache Tomcat AS, it provide three ways to configure DataSource in JNDI.

1- in your application: context.xml under META-INF directory.

2- in your server context.xml under Tomcat/conf directory.

3- define it at global level by setting both server.xml and context.xml

I prefer the third way, so for Oracle Database declare the JNDI resource in your in your Tomcat/conf/server.xml like:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/DATABASE_NAME"
        auth=Container
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        username="db_username"
        password="db_password"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:XE"
/>
....
```

and for MySQL Database do:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource name="jdbc/DATABASE_NAME"
            auth=Container
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username="db_username"
            password="db_password"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME"
    />
....
```

And reference the JNDI resource link in your Tomcat/conf/context.xml :

```
<Context>
   <ResourceLink name="jdbc/MY_DATABASE_NAME" global="jdbc/DATABASE_NAME" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

and finally use the ResourceLink's name in your project to get the DataSource.

hope it help.